# Changing from Positive to Negative

Tags: soft-question, summation

*I may mess up a little bit...Sorry for that!*

When we want a summation to go negative in case of odd numbers and positive otherwise , we use:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{12} \color{red}{{(-1)}^i} 2x^3 $$

But what if I want it to go positive for say $i=1$ to $i=8$ and then turn negative **Without using**:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{8} 2x^3 \space + \space \sum\limits_{i=9}^{12} -2x^3$$

> I mean i want to use the condition in just one summation instead of splitting things up...Then what to do?
>
> $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{12} {(-1)}^{\color{blue}{?}} 2x^3$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid splitting things up? The answers you got (one of which you accepted) just hide it under the rug.  If we know the motivation, there may be a better answer.  On the other hand, we often see questions that don't like functions that have cases.  A function defined by cases is a fine function-all that is required is a unique output for each input in the domain.

Comment: @RossMillikan I was just thinking whether it was possible! Actually the motivation was that the problem which i was doing (HomeWork!) actually consisted of many of these in one line so i thought whether it would be possible to make it a little shorter! Nothing else!!

Comment: If it is homework, it is probably arranged that many terms will cancel.  Splitting them out may show you which ones do.

Comment: @RossMillikan All right all right....!! "Curiosity" OK?

Comment: This is an ongoing frustration for me.  If you ask somebody to go to the board and draw a function, it is clearly $C^1$ and probably $C^\infty$, but most functions are not even continuous.  This leads people to think all functions are rather smooth, which is false.  Then they resist case definitions because they believe they are discontinuous (which they may be, but may not be).

Comment: @RossMillikan I still don't understand why are we arguing!

Comment: My last was not an argument, it was explaining where I was coming from before.  No issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cheeky way of doing it: define $f(i) = \begin{cases} 0 & i \leq 8 \\ 1 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$, and plug in $? = f(i)$. But that's lame.

One thing you can do that might be what you're looking for but will definitely make whatever you're doing less understandable is to play with the floor function. If you don't know, $\lfloor x \rfloor$, the floor of $x$, is just $x$ rounded down to the greatest integer below it. In this case, $? = \lfloor i/9 \rfloor$ would do what you want it to do, but it feels like cheating.

Comment: Actually it is $\Big\lfloor \dfrac{i}{9} \Big\rfloor$! Please edit! BTW thanks!

Comment: whoops! I guess I wasn't thinking.

Comment: @NeilRoy Defining a new function, or using characteristic function notation $1_{i>8}$, is the best way to go about it. Using floor of $i$ over 9 factorial will just confuse people with unnecessary detail. There's no rule saying you have to use only the functions that were given to you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the sign function but you would want to make sure it doesn't land on zero

so in your case

$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sgn} \sum_{i=1}{\sign(17-2i)2x^3} $$

$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sgn}
\sign(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
-1 & x<0 \\ 
 0& x=0 \\ 
 1& x>0 
\end{matrix}\right. $$

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\sign}{sign} $$